# eBay Trading API - AddItems call returns error 21359 - Request time out

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I've been working on uploading an item feed to eBay automatically and I'm stumped when I effectively make the API call. I keep getting `Error 21395 - Request time out`.

Of course so far I've only used the Sandbox Credentials (as per requested by eBay) and I am also sticking to the maximum upload of 5 products per feed (in fact I'm only uploading 3, and even tried with 1 or 2). Also tried it in their "DEV/API Test Tool" but to no avail, it even fails when using the eBay-provided model XML. There is no documentation anywhere, and their Git Repository has not been updated in the last year and a half.

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my Test XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AddItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <AddItemRequestContainer>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <Item>
      <Title>Harry Potter 1</Title>
      <Description>First Book</Description>
      <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
      <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryId>279</CategoryId>
      </PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
      <Site>DE</Site>
      <Quantity>500</Quantity>
      <StartPrice>10</StartPrice>
      <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
      <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
      <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
      <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost>2.5</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
      </ShippingDetails>
      <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        <Description>Description of Return Policy Details</Description>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
      </ReturnPolicy>
      <Country>DE</Country>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <PostalCode>76927</PostalCode>
      <PaymentMethods>AmEx</PaymentMethods>
      <PictureDetails>
        <Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL></Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>
        <PictureURL></PictureURL>
      </PictureDetails>
      <UUID>e652668dbb984fd193db3e4af000a078</UUID>
    </Item>
  </AddItemRequestContainer>
  <AddItemRequestContainer>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <Item>
      <Title>Harry Potter 2</Title>
      <Description>Second Book</Description>
      <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
      <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryId>279</CategoryId>
      </PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
      <Site>DE</Site>
      <Quantity>100</Quantity>
      <StartPrice>12</StartPrice>
      <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
      <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
      <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
      <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost>2.5</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
      </ShippingDetails>
      <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        <Description>Description of Return Policy Details</Description>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
      </ReturnPolicy>
      <Country>DE</Country>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <PostalCode>76927</PostalCode>
      <PaymentMethods>AmEx</PaymentMethods>
      <PictureDetails>
        <Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>harrypotter.com/books/2.jpg</Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>
        <PictureURL>harrypotter.com/books/2.jpg</PictureURL>
      </PictureDetails>
      <UUID>e652668dbb984fd193db3e4af000a079</UUID>
    </Item>
  </AddItemRequestContainer>
  <AddItemRequestContainer>
    <MessageID>3</MessageID>
    <Item>
      <Title>Harry Potter 3</Title>
      <Description>Third Book</Description>
      <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
      <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryId>279</CategoryId>
      </PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
      <Site>DE</Site>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <StartPrice>100</StartPrice>
      <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
      <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
      <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
      <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
          <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
          <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
          <ShippingServiceCost>2.5</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
      </ShippingDetails>
      <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        <Description>Description of Return Policy Details</Description>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
      </ReturnPolicy>
      <Country>DE</Country>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <PostalCode>76927</PostalCode>
      <PaymentMethods>AmEx</PaymentMethods>
      <PictureDetails>
        <Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>harrypotter.com/books/3.jpg</Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL>
        <PictureURL>harrypotter.com/books/3.jpg</PictureURL>
      </PictureDetails>
      <UUID>e652668dbb984fd193db3e4af000a080</UUID>
    </Item>
  </AddItemRequestContainer>
  <RequesterCredentials>
 <eBayAuthToken> --My AUTH Token-- </eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</AddItemsRequest>
```

Comment: what language/library are you using to post that XML? i've found i have to increase the default timeout to up to several minutes to ensure eBay has enough time to process my request and return a response.

Comment: i wrote the whole thing in PHP. I actually managed to overcome the time out, but i honestly dont remember how i did it. i guess there was an error in my code afterall